# How to parse a complex xml in Rinto a dataframe?

Tags: r, xml

I want to parse a nested xml file with the layout below in R and load it into a dataframe.  I tried using several eays including the xml and xml2 packages but could not get it to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Targets>
<Target TYPE="myserver.mgmt.Metric" NAME="metric1">
<Attribute NAME="name" VALUE="metric1"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="Value" VALUE="2.4"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="collectionTime" VALUE="1525118288000"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="State" VALUE="normal"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="ObjectName" VALUE="obj1"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="ValueHistory" VALUE="5072"></Attribute>
</Target>
...
<Target TYPE="myserver.mgmt.Metric" NAME="metric999">
<Attribute NAME="name" VALUE="metric999"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="Value" VALUE="60.35"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="collectionTime" VALUE="1525118288000"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="State" VALUE="normal"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="ObjectName" VALUE="obj1"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="ValueHistory" VALUE="9550"></Attribute>
</Target>
</Targets>
```

The final outcome I am looking to get is:

```
name    Value   collectionTime  State   ObjectName  ValueHistory
metric1 2.4     1525118288000   normal  obj1        5072
metric2 60.35   1525118288000   normal  obj2        9550
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make use of `XML` with `tidyverse`

```
library(XML)
library(tidyverse)
lst1 <- getNodeSet(xml1, path = "//Target")
map_df(seq_along(lst1), ~ 
     XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(lst1[[.x]])  %>% 
        mutate_all(as.character) %>%
        deframe %>%
        as.list %>% 
        as_tibble) %>%
        mutate_all(type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#  name      Value collectionTime State  ObjectName ValueHistory
#  <chr>     <dbl>          <dbl> <chr>  <chr>             <int>
#1 metric1     2.4  1525118288000 normal obj1               5072
#2 metric999  60.4  1525118288000 normal obj1               9550
```

#### data

```
xml1 <- xmlParse('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Targets>
<Target TYPE="myserver.mgmt.Metric" NAME="metric1">
<Attribute NAME="name" VALUE="metric1"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="Value" VALUE="2.4"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="collectionTime" VALUE="1525118288000"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="State" VALUE="normal"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="ObjectName" VALUE="obj1"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="ValueHistory" VALUE="5072"></Attribute>
</Target>
<Target TYPE="myserver.mgmt.Metric" NAME="metric999">
<Attribute NAME="name" VALUE="metric999"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="Value" VALUE="60.35"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="collectionTime" VALUE="1525118288000"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="State" VALUE="normal"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="ObjectName" VALUE="obj1"></Attribute>
<Attribute NAME="ValueHistory" VALUE="9550"></Attribute>
</Target>
</Targets>
')
```